# E2E tests with multiple pages with information from browser

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am writing an E2E test with protractor. I had to fetch information from the browser and execute a step multiple times.

I am testing one screen which will start when a

- User clicks 'Start'
- lands on a new page
- The workflow below is invoked with count being passed as argument
- `id` the html id does not change. the value changes when queried again after submitting the current form.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
   console.log("counter is "+i);
   element(by('id')).evaluate('value').then(function(v) {
    // do some action on UI based on v
    element(by('id1')).sendKeys(v+v);
    // submit etc., 
    // some angular code runs in the frontend.
   }
   // need to wait since webdriver jumps to the next one without this completing
}
```

Many blog posts/documentations suggests you cannot use it in a loop, but does not suggest any alternative way to do this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

> Never use protractor element statements inside loop: The simple reason is that the webdriverJS (protractor) API is asynchronous. Element statements returns a promise and that promise is in unresolved state while the code below the statements continues to execute. This leads to unpredictable results. Hence, it is advisable to use recursive functions instead of loops.

source: http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/angularapp-e2e-testing-with-protractor/

Edit: updated question with details of workflow.

Comment: can you put some more details in the question .. like .. how is the `count` value determined and does the `id` change with every value in loop . May be some context top answer this better

Comment: `count` is passed from another function. `id` element changes in the frontend, but the value during evaluation does not change. will update the question too.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually not recommended to use a loop when an iteration has an asynchronous call.

The reason is that the first asynchronous calls is executed after the last iteration of the loop when `i` is already equal to `count`.
Thus, it makes it difficult to break the loop and to keep track of the value of `i`.

On way to tackle the issue is to use a recursive function :

```
var count = 3;
var results = [];

function iterate(i, n) {
  if(i < n) {
    console.log(`counter is ${i}`);

    browser.refresh();
    return element(by.id('h-top-questions')).getText().then(function(text) {
      results.push(`${i}:${text}`);
      return iterate(i + 1, n);
    });
  }
}

iterate(0, count).then(function(){
  console.log("done!", results);
});
```

But a better way would be to iterate with `promise.map` on an array sized to the number of iterations:

```
var count = 3;

protractor.promise.map(Array(count).fill(0), function(v, i) {
  console.log(`counter is ${i}`);

  browser.refresh();
  return element(by.id('h-top-questions')).getText().then(function(text) {
    return `${i}:${text}`;
  });
}).then(function(results){
  console.log("done!", results);
});
```

You could also keep using a loop. First you'll have to use the `let` statement to get the value of `i` in an asynchronous function (ES6). 
Then call all the synchronous code with `browser.call` to synchronize the execution:

```
var count = 3;
var results = [];

for(let i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
  browser.call(function(){
    console.log(`counter is ${i}`);

    browser.refresh();
    element(by.id('h-top-questions')).getText().then(function(text) {
      results.push(`${i}:${text}`);
    });
  });
}

browser.call(function() {
  console.log("done!", results);
});
```

Comment: The page has some dynamic data modified or used from the previous iteration of the loop and cannot use `refresh`. The view in the page only has one text field and one input box with a progress bar of sorts.

Comment: @Sairam, the refresh is just here as an example to observe the order of execution. For the result of a previous iteration, you can get it in `results[i - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Looping in protractor works like this

```
describe('Describe something', function() {
    var testParams = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    beforeEach( function() {
        // ...
   });

for (var i = 0; i < testParams.length; i++) {
  (function (testSpec) {
    it('should do something', function() {
        // inside loop
    });

  })(testParams[i]);

};
});
```

Edit : I might be mis-understanding your question, but it seems to me you want to complete all(dynamic count) actions on the page, before going to the next one ?

```
it('should clear old inspections', function() {  
                  inspectieModuleInspectieFixture.getRemoveInspectionButton().count().then(function (value) {
                        if(value == 0){
                            console.log('--- no inspections to remove ---');
                        }
                        for(var i = 0; i < value; i++){
                            //global.waitForClickable(inspectieModuleInspectieFixture.getRemoveInspectionButtonList(i+1));
                            inspectieModuleInspectieFixture.getRemoveInspectionButtonList(i+1).click();
                            console.log('iteration '+i + 'count '+value )
                        };
                    });
                    global.wait(5000);

            }); */
```

this counts elements on the page and then it performs an action for the ammount of elements it found

In the above example I use containers to hold my elements, so my code remains readable (i.e. inspectieModuleInspectieFixture.getRemoveInspectionButton() holds $(".elementSelectorExample")

There is also a 'global.waitForClickable' commented, that is reffering to a 'time module' I've created that extends the functionality of 'wait', in this case it waits till the element is vissible/clickable.

This is easily mirrored perhaps something like this :

```
    waitForElementNoDisplay: function(element){
    return browser.wait(function() {
        return element.isDisplayed().then(function(present) {
            return !present;
        })
    });
},
```

this will make protractor WAIT untill an element is no longer displayed.(Display:none)

Comment: Great solution. Never thought about it this way. 

what do I do if I have 2 level nesting of `for` loops.

I have set of pages to go through and set of actions in each page. 

Could you please point to the documentation or best practices for Protractor?

Comment: @Sairam Alas, I do not think Protractor condones looping at all, so I can not seem to find any documentation on how to implement it 'correctly'. This is a snippet I got off some other person on SO.

I also gave up on trying to implement it in a real test suite, I found the added 'complexity' is just not what we wanted for our tests, I was better off copying the config file's and adjusting them a little bit.

[snip]

Edit : I think nesting looping might not be what you want, you might want something like this ( see edit post )

Comment: global.wait is bad for my case since there could be too many. I was looking for the `for` loop mainly and putting `it` inside it.

Comment: @Sairam ill be honest, global.wait should never be used! I just put it in there for clarification purposes and in hindsight I should have left it out, but I'm glad the looping example has been of use!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform some action on every element, it is true, that better to not use loops. Use .map() or .each() or .filter() instead

Still not quite sure what you what to do, but here is example how i am doing similar tasks, when you need to make number of actions depending on data from the page:

```
class SomePage {

    typeValueForEachElement(elements) {
        elements.each((elem, index)=> {
            elem.getAttribute('value').then(value=> {
                elem.sendKeys(value + value)
                elem.submit()
            })
        })

    }
}

new SomePage().typeValueForEachElement($$('your locator here'))
```

Here is api reference that might help

> http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map
>   http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce
>   http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each
>   http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter

Comment: I am performing operations on the same element . but I need to perform `n` times based on the input from the previous screen.